# Django DateTimeField can't validate ISO 8601 format

Tags: python, django

Django DateTimeField can't validate  ISO 8601 format

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    updatedAfter = forms.DateTimeField()
    createdAfter = forms.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
class ImageView(View)
    def get_form(self):
        return ImageForm(data=self.request.GET or None)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
              ...
```

Here is my request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/images/?updatedAfter=2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z&createdAfter=2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```

Comment: Have you tried it without milliseconds?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Nope, because I must support ISO 8601 where can be milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the following settings, it worked for me:

**settings.py**

```
USE_L10N = False

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ',)
```

Comment: This should be edited to retain the default values or mention that it removes the default values.

Comment: It's true, this may affect the rest of your project, as it is a global setting. This formatting can also be applied to individual Form fields.